# HttpWebRequest Post synchronous call - TimeOut not working

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, timeout

My webrequest timeout does not seem to be working. The URL that host has some TLS setting issue. But even in cases of exceptions, is it not expected to respect the timeout?
The hostname has the domain name and not IP.Please let me know what I am missing for the timeout to work at 30secs immaterial of success/exception scenarios.
Find the code below - we have currently kept the timeout to be 30s but recieving the response after 1.15mins or more.

```
public string CallJsonService(string JsonString, string ServiceURL, string strLogUser, string RandomValue, string strAPIToCall)
        {
            string displayvalue = "";
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                byte[] bytestream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonString);
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServiceURL);

                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                req.ContentLength = bytestream.LongLength;
                req.Timeout = 30000;
                req.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                String ProxyValue = objCommon.GetParamValue("ProxyValueForInstant");
                req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyValue, true);
                req.Headers.Add("vRanKey", Convert.ToString(RandomValue));
                req.Accept = "application/json";

                using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(bytestream, 0, bytestream.Length);
                    stream.Flush();
                }

                using (WebResponse responserequest = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream ResponseStream = responserequest.GetResponseStream();
                    displayvalue = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((new StreamReader(ResponseStream)).ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                            {
                                displayvalue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return displayvalue;
        }
```

Comment: TLS is performed "before" the request is sent in the operating system.  Adding timeouts in the request is after the TLS is occurring.

Comment: @jdweng So you mean to say, the timeouts wont be applicable because of the TLS issue? We are getting "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." exception.

Comment: Error message can be confusing.  SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and Microsoft pushed Windows updates to disable these versions on server two year ago.  If your target version of Net is before 4.7.2 encryption modes have bugs with TLS and do not work.  To make sure TLS works you need to use Net 4.7.2 or later. Starting with Net 4.7.2   TLS is done in operating system (not inside Net) and bugs have been fixed.  Also you need to use a version of Windows where Microsoft fixed the encryption bugs.  And finally with 4.7.2 there is an option to use for TLS Net of OS and you must use OS,

Comment: Yes we are using Net 4.7.2 and our server is Windows Server 2012 R2. TLS issue is from the host end and we are waiting for resolution from their end. In the meantime we need the timeout to work. So Is there a work around for timeout?

Comment: You should remove TLS 1.0 and 1.1 from  : SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;  Server need to be upgraded to support TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3.  With TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of Certificates.  Than client looks up in stores the name(s) to find matching certificate.  You can see the certificate block with names if you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Any timeout for TLS would have to handled in the ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

Comment: You may have an issue with the encryption mode.  Default padding mode for RSA could be different in JSON and Windows.  Or the encryption mode may not be supported in the OS.  You can open the certifcate with notepad and check encryption mode.  See following for more info on the encryption mode : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true

Comment: ServerCertificateValidationCallback is used when you want only a specific certificate to be used.  The TLS certificate block usually contains multiple certificate names and ServerCertificateValidationCallback is used to make sure only the certificate you want is used.  Some people used the routine to get the encryption to work to get around the issues with version of Net before 4.7.2 not supporting all the encryption modes.  With 4.72 or later it is no longer needed except if you want to used a specific certificate.